# What is the proper understanding of the phrase מִפְעָלָיו מֵאָֽז, "works of old" in Proverbs?

Tags: hebrew, proverbs

> The LORD possessed me in the beginning of his way, before his works of old.
> (Proverbs 8:22 KJV)

> יְֽהוָה קָנָנִי רֵאשִׁית דַּרְכֹּו קֶדֶם **מִפְעָלָיו מֵאָֽז**

It is common to understand "works of old" to refer to creation and then the verse speaks to "wisdom" being an integral part of creation. "Works" is [מִפְעָל](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H4659&t=KJV), which is only used in two other places:

> Come, behold the works of the LORD, what desolations he hath made in the earth.
> (Psalm 46:8)
> Come and see the works of God: he is terrible in his doing toward the children of men.
> (Psalm 66:5)

Obviously these are works God does after creation done specifically to get man's attention:

- Believers to place confidence in the LORD (Psalm 46)
- Invite all people to consider God's works in the Exodus (Psalm 66)

Given the other uses, it seems to mean works of salvation, not works of creation.

Answer (score 2):

#1. What is the literal understanding of "MiPealiu MeAz" ( מִפְעָלָיו מֵאָז) From Proverbs 8:22?

[ מִפְעָלָ֣יו ] "MiPealiu":

In Hebrew, the prefix 'Mi' (מִ) = "of" in English. + 'Paal' (פְעָלָ) = "Work" in English. + The third person singular suffix - 'iu' (יו) = "His" in English.

- Mi-Peal-iu (מִפְעָלָ֣יו) : Of-Work-His / "Of His Work".

[ מֵאָֽז ] "Me-az':

In Hebrew, the prepositional prefix 'Me' (מֵ) = "From" in English. + 'Az' (אָֽז) = "Then" in English.

- Me-Az (מֵאָֽז) : From-Then / "From Before".

[ מִפְעָלָיו מֵאָז ] "MiPealiu Meaz":

In English the literal translation of [ מִפְעָלָיו מֵאָז ] "MiPealiu Meaz" = "of His Work from Then". However, the traditional English translation from Mishlei 8:22 [MT] renders "of His Works of old. "

#2. Did "His Works from Then" in context to Proverbs 8 verses 27-29 relate to Creation?

[Proverbs 8:27]:

*He established the heavens.
*He drew a circle over the face of the deep.

[Proverbs 8:28]:

*He made the skies above firm.
*He strengthened the fountains of the deep.

[Proverbs 8:29]

*He gave the sea its boundary.
*He established the foundations of the earth.

- Yes. The phrase "MiPealiu MeAz" ( מִפְעָלָיו מֵאָז) in Proverbs 8 relates to the Works of His Creation.

Comment: this is an excellent understanding of the meaning of the Hebrew phrase but the question (as I understand it) asks about the works to which this verse refers.  Presumably, things that God has done in times past - old historical acts of God as often recorded in the early books of the Bible.

Comment: Thanks, Dottard!  I have updated the Answer to reflect the "Works" of Psalm 8 in context related to the Creation narrative of Bereishit (Genesis) 1:1-11.

Comment: I like how you approached this and made your case. +1

Comment: Thanks (תּוֹדָה), Ruminator!

Comment: I think קָ֭נָנִי enters into the analysis and maybe should have been part of the question. It can be possessed or purchased. So *YHVH purchased/possessed me before His works of old*...and then describing works of creation does not automatically mean the works are also creative. For example, the same sentiment is found in the NT in several places: *just as He chose us in Him before the foundation of the world...* (Ephesians 1:4). God is responsible for both, enumerating the works of creation does not eliminate works of salvation.